# Assigning value to form input by "id” and not by “value” attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is my current situation:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', calculateTotal);

const calculator = document.querySelector("form");

function cake() {
    const cakes = Array.from(calculator.elements["cake"]).slice(0, 3);
    const raphael = calculator.elements["raphael"];

    function isChecked(checkbox) {
        return checkbox.checked;
    }

    var count = cakes.filter(isChecked).length;
    if (count) {
        count = count * 0.5 + 0.5;
    }
    if (raphael.checked) {
        count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}

function occasion() {
    const occasionOptions = {
        birthday: 25,
        anniversary: 50,
        wedding: 100
    }

    var occasionCost = 0;
    const occasion = calculator.elements["occasion"];

    for (var i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
        if (occasion[i].checked) {
            occasionCost = occasionOptions[occasion[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
    return occasionCost;
}

function calculateTotal() {
    var totalCost = cake() * occasion();
    calculator.total.value = "$" + totalCost.toLocaleString("en");
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Cakes</legend>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="leonardo" required>Leonardo</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="donatello">Donatello</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="michelangelo">Michelangelo</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="raphael">Raphael</label>
        <p>If you select more than one cake, the other cakes are discounted 50%.</p>
        <p><small>Does not apply to Raphael.</small></p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose Occasion</legend>
        <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="birthday">Birthday</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="anniversary">Anniversary</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" value="wedding">Wedding</label>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="text" name="total">
</form>
```

In the example above, I would like to switch `value` to `id` attribute on `input radio`. If I for example replace `value="birthday"` to `id="birthday"`, the values are no longer assigned to `input`.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Code snippet updated to include both `id` and `value` in fieldsets.)

Comment: Why do you want to switch `value` to `id`?

Comment: For consistency reasons, as I have many fieldsets in my form.

Comment: `value` and `id` serve different purposes.  You don't get the value of a radio button from its `id` attribute.  That isn't what it is for.

Comment: What do you mean for consistency? What about the fieldsets?

Comment: So you recommend I keep `value`?

Comment: Right, I do not recommend misusing the `id` attribute like this, and can't think of a compelling reason why that might be useful.  It's just going to break stuff.  Submitting a form?  A form gets its data from the name/value attributes of its form elements.  It isn't going to get its data from the name/id attributes.

Comment: I updated my code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HTMLElement.id` to get the `id` of an element.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', calculateTotal);

const calculator = document.querySelector("form");

function occasion() {
    const occasionOptions = {
        birthday: 2.5,
        anniversary: 5,
        wedding: 10
    }

    var occasionCost = 0;
    const occasion = calculator.elements["occasion"];

    for (var i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
        if (occasion[i].checked) {
            occasionCost = occasionOptions[occasion[i].id];
            break;
        }
    }
    return occasionCost;
}

function calculateTotal() {
    var totalCost = 100 * occasion();
    calculator.total.value = "$" + totalCost.toLocaleString("en");
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose Occasion</legend>
        <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="birthday">Birthday</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="anniversary">Anniversary</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="wedding">Wedding</label>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="text" name="total">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

i do not know the rationale for using id property over value, but if that is what you want to do, all you need to do is to update your js to read id property instead of value property.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBvYoL

HTML:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Choose Occasion</legend>
<label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="birthday">Birthday</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="anniversary">Anniversary</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="wedding">Wedding</label>
</fieldset>

<input type="text" name="total">
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', calculateTotal);

const calculator = document.querySelector("form");

function occasion() {
 const occasionOptions = {
  birthday: 2.5,
  anniversary: 5,
  wedding: 10
 }

 var occasionCost = 0;
 const occasion = calculator.elements["occasion"];

 for (var i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
  if (occasion[i].checked) {
   occasionCost = occasionOptions[occasion[i].id];
   break;
  }
 }
 return occasionCost;
}

function calculateTotal() {
 var totalCost = 100 * occasion();
 calculator.total.value = "$" + totalCost.toLocaleString("en");
}
```